# How can I vertically align all elements in a list of text?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to align these elements in my Angular application - date, file total and file size. 
If there is a larger number with more digits, then it is pushing the other elements away.
I have tried changing the padding margins and have tried display: Flex, inline and inline-block.
I want the start of each element to line up even if the numbers have more digits or less, so say we have - Apr 1, 2019    1 file   3445 G  the start of each element will line up with Mar 28, 2019  34 files   29282 G.

The elements are in spans with a class of jobdate-item-date, jobdate-item-file-total and jobdate-item-file-length. 
When you click on these they open up showing lists of job data. Here is a picture and my current code -

Html -

```
      <div *ngFor="let date of selectedJob.dates" class="card-date-file">
        <div class="detail-item" (click)="toggle()">
          <span class="jobdate-item-date">{{ date.date | date: 'MMM dd, y' }}</span>
          <span class="jobdate-item-file-total">{{ date.files.length }} files</span>
          <span class="jobdate-item-file-length">{{ jobFileCalc(date.files) }} GB</span>
        </div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="show">
        <div *ngFor="let file of date.files" class="list" >
          <span class="file-item-filename">{{ file.filename }}</span>
          <span class="file-item-incr">{{ file.incr? 'INCR':'FULL' }}</span>
          <span class="file-item-time">{{ file.dttm | date:'h:mm' }}{{ file.dttm | date:'a' | lowercase }}</span>
          <span class="file-item-size">{{ file.sizegb.toFixed(1)| number : fractionSize }} GB</span>
        </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
.jobdate-item-date {
  padding: 0.1em 1.1em 0.3em 0.8em;
}

.jobdate-item-file-total {
  padding: 0.3em 1.1em 0.3em 1.1em;
}

.jobdate-item-file-length {
  padding: 0.3em 1.1em 0.3em 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? you want to sort by date field and display according to it?

Comment: why not use a table if it's tabular data?  Then you should be able to align it how you want, otherwise instead of using padding, give the spans a width

Comment: yeah thats what I'm trying to do at the moment, if there is a better way though I will try it. So you see in the picture due to the bigger digits on Mar 31, 2019 is pushing the 14 file and 4938.8 G. So would be good to align  the start of each element if possible.

Comment: Yes, this is what tables are for. Make your app more accessible and semantic and switch over to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give every element a certain width (I used flexbox in my example), and if it is too long, you could truncate the text with some ellipses if you'd like. You can of-course play with the widths, or use percentages to achieve your wanted results.

```css
.detail-item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
}

.jobdate-item-date,
.jobdate-item-file-total, 
.jobdate-item-file-length {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail-item" (click)="toggle()">
  <span class="jobdate-item-date">Mar 29, 2019</span>
  <span class="jobdate-item-file-total">12 files</span>
  <span class="jobdate-item-file-length">2280.2 GB</span>
</div>

<div class="detail-item" (click)="toggle()">
  <span class="jobdate-item-date">Apr 3, 2019</span>
  <span class="jobdate-item-file-total">2 files</span>
  <span class="jobdate-item-file-length">99.2 GB</span>
</div>

<div class="detail-item" (click)="toggle()">
  <span class="jobdate-item-date">Apr 3, 2019</span>
  <span class="jobdate-item-file-total">2 files</span>
  <span class="jobdate-item-file-length">324324234234234232423 GB</span>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect. and you can add media-query for responsive design too.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I am using *ngFor to get and display the data on the template. So the amount of rows of elements will be dependent on the data so I can't lay it out like that. Thank you though

Comment: Wait, I can still work with this. This has certainly helped. Thank you @elDrimm